# Mysql update where records don't exist in table

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I need some help with an MySQL update.  I have 2 tables as follows:

```
**Inventory**
  vmvcenter
  vmid
  hostname

**Guest_import**
  vmvcenter
  vmid
  discrepancy
```

I need to put a 'YES' in the guest_import.discrepancy column if the record does not exist in the inventory table.  The key between the tables should be CONCAT(vmvcenter,vmid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update guest_import g
left join Inventory i on i.vmvcenter = g.vmvcenter and i.vmid = g.vmid
set discrepancy = 'YES'
where i.vmvcenter is null
```